# push subscription error not triggering catch

Tags: javascript, push-notification, es6-promise, service-worker, push-api

I am trying to take a specific action if my push registration fails. To make the subscription fail, I have removed the `<link>` to the `manifest.json` file (I'm using Chrome). I get the following error as expected:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Registration failed - manifest empty or missing
```

However this error comes from `index.html:1` rather than `main.js`, where the subscription code lives:

```js
function subscribe() {
  navigator.serviceWorker.ready
  .then(function(reg) {
    reg.pushManager.getSubscription()
    .then(function(sub) {
      if (!sub) {
        reg.pushManager.subscribe({userVisibleOnly: true})
        .then(function(subscription) {
          console.log('Subscribed to push,', subscription);
        });
      } else {
        console.log('Already subscribed');
      }
    });
  })
  .catch(function(e) {
    console.log('catch!');
    // Do something
  });
}
```

And (I suspect as a result) the `catch` block is not triggering. Is this correct behavior or am I likely doing something wrong?

More details:
I am trying to simulate offline behavior, which is why I have removed the link to `manifest.json` (which would be unavailable offline unless cached). If the subscription fails because the app is offline, I'd like to take action in the `catch` (e.g. queue an analytics hit or update UI).

Comment: .catch has to be handled for reg.pushManager.getSubscription().then().catch()  to check for subscription failed or not

Comment: Ah! Of course. I don't know how I got this far using promises without knowing that. I had assumed that an error/reject would "bubble up". Thanks!! Just as FYI, its actually the `reg.pushManager.subscribe({userVisibleOnly: true})` that is throwing, so the `catch` needs to be on that level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @bvakiti said in his comment, a `catch` block must be on the same "level" as the rejecting promise. Since in this case the `reg.pushManager.subscribe({userVisibleOnly: true})` code is whats throwing the error, there needs to be a `catch` on the end of that promise chain. Updated code:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.ready
.then(function(reg) {
  reg.pushManager.getSubscription()
  .then(function(sub) {
    if (!sub) {
      reg.pushManager.subscribe({userVisibleOnly: true})
      .then(function(subscription) {
        console.log('Subscribed to push,', subscription);
      })
      // Catch here now!
      .catch(function(e) {
        console.log('catch statements must be on the same level!');
      });
    } else {
      console.log('Already subscribed');
    }
  }); // could add catch here too
}); // no catch needed here, serviceWorker.ready never rejects
```

Note that for the other async "levels", I would also need to add catches for their corresponding promises, as shown with comments (except for `serviceWorker.ready` promise, which actually [never rejects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/ready).